# How to fix hash sum mismatch errors when doing apt-get update by using the Acquire-by-hash option?

Tags: apt, hashsum

When I do an apt-get update, I get a hash sum mismatch error for one of my local repositories.

I have already read the solutions on here and in other places, but those solutions don't apply because I believe that this is a server-side error.

I did find several things which talk about setting an option available in 16.04 called `Acquire-by-hash` to yes. But it wasn't very clear to me how to use this option.

In which file exactly do you use this option, and what does the entry look like?

Answer (score 3):

As root:

```
sudo -s
echo "Acquire::By-Hash \"yes\"; ">/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01byhash
apt update
```

Regards

Comment: Still fail hash check